# Why is OpenCV StereoCalibrate function changing a local variable which is fed as input?

Tags: python, opencv, variables

Hey I am trying to understand what is happening when I call cv2.stereoCalibrate as it does seem to mess with my variables... Following code illustrates the issue for the numpy **array K01**:

```
    self.K01, self.D01 = load_coefficients(path)
    
    self.K02, self.D02 = load_coefficients(path2)

    print('K01:', K01)
```

K01 matrix prints:

```
    array([[2.31510096e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 7.21346331e+02],
           [0.00000000e+00, 2.31473055e+03, 5.00531281e+02],
           [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

```
    stereoParameters = cv2.stereoCalibrate(self.objpoints, 
                                           self.left_imgpoints, 
                                           self.right_imgpoints, 
                                           self.K01, self.D01, 
                                           self.K02, self.D02, 
                                           self.image_format, 
                                           flags = calib_flags, 
                                           criteria=calib_criteria)   
    print("Stereo calibration rms:", self.ret)
    print('K01 after stereoCalibrate',self.K01)
```

K01 after calling stereoCalibrate prints:

```
    array([[3.34185693e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 5.61957072e+02],
           [0.00000000e+00, 4.81426914e+04, 7.05288783e+02],
           [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

has anyone noticed similair behaviour before and/or can explain to me why this happens?
Any idea would be highly appreciated!

Comment: maybe you should send copy `self.K01.copy()`.

Comment: when you send `list`, `dict`, `array` then Python doesn't copy data but it sends reference to original data (because it is faster and easier, and sometimes people expect it) but if function makes modification on this data then you see this also in your original variable - and then you have to maunally copy data.

Comment: that's because *OpenCV* treats that argument (a numpy array) as an "in-out" argument, i.e. it'll modify it.